# Get individual headers from CURL with Regex Group

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to get all the headers of a bash CURL command using RegEx group capturing, but I'm having a problem where it's just grabbing all the headers in one group (and another group that I don't exactly know why it's happening).

The bash:

```
curl '<url>' -H 'origin: <url>' -H 'accept-endocing: <...>' -H 'accept-language: <...>' <continues with more headers> --data '<...>'
```

and it goes on with other headers.

The code:

```
var rawBash = RawBash.Text;
var headerPattern = @"\-H[\s][\']{1}(.+)[\']{1}";
var headers = Regex.Match(rawBash, headerPattern);
```

I've [tested the pattern here](http://regexr.com/) and it says "11 Captures", and 'correctly' indicates the groups I want captured, but when I debug the code it indicates that 2 groups were captured:

1. The entire CURL starting with the first "-H"
2. The entire CURL starting with "origin:"

What's happening? I'm guessing the Regex is taking the `(.+)` and not terminating when it hits the `[\']{1}` because `'` matches `(.+)`... but how do I make it capture each individual header in a group?

I've tried to read through a few C# RegEx tutorials/descriptions, but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for (or describe what I'm looking for in the correct wording).

**EDIT:** Literally seconds after posting I had the idea to try this pattern:

```
var headerPattern = @"\-H[\s][\']{1}([^\']+)[\']{1}";
```

Notice the group is now `([^\']+)` instead of `(.+)`. It is now working as I want it to.

Also, I'm using `Regex.Match(...)`, and it should be `Regex.Matches(...)` to get all the matches.

But I guess the question sort of still stands; how can someone terminate a group capture at a point? I'm recalling a friend using the term `forward lookup` in what I believe was a similar situation, but I have no idea how to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the effects of greedy vs lazy (or non-greedy) matching.

Greedy matching will match as many characters as possible
Lazy matching will only match as many characters as required.

In your original pattern `(.+)` is a greedy matching of one or more or any character. So it will grab from your first `-H '` to the last `'`

What you changed it to, `([^\']+)`, is also greedy, but its terminating early because its not matching any character, its only matching characters that are not a `'`.

You can change a `*` or `+` to lazy by adding a `?` directly after.

My solution to your header matcher is (assuming your example string is fairly representative of a consistent format).

```
\-H\s+\'(.+?)\'
```

Your friend is referring to a positive lookahead. This looks forward in the string to get a successful match, however what it matches on is not part of the full match string. The syntax is `(?=...)`. There is also a negative lookahead `(?!...)` and positive and negative lookbehinds, `(?<=...)` and `(?<!...)` respectively. They should be used with caution as they can be really inefficient on longer strings.

For example take the following 2 strings:

```
regex isnt always the right answer|this will match

regex isnt always the right answer|this will not
```

if I used the following pattern:

```
regex (is.*) always (the right answer(?=.*this will match))
```

will result in this for the first string:

```
Full match  0-34    `regex isnt always the right answer`
Group 1.    6-10    `isnt`
Group 2.    18-34   `the right answer`
```

and will not match the second at all.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick reply! If I'm understanding it correctly, the `?` forces lazy because it is essentially going to perform `0||1` on the preceding `0+`/`1+` to ensure the minimum match?

Comment: the `?` is just the syntax for doing a lazy repeating character - http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html